# Expand tuple into arguments while casting them?

Tags: python, tuples, iterable-unpacking

I have this:

```
blah = random.randint(int(minmax[0]), int(minmax[1]))
```

I know this is possible:

```
minimum, maximum = int(minmax[0]), int(minmax[1])
blah = random.randint(minimum, maximum)
```

Can I do this second one in a single line using tuple-argument expansion?
For example, if minmax was a tuple of integers to begin with, I could do:

```
blah = random.randint(*minmax)
```

But I don't have a tuple of ints, I have a tuple of strs. Obviously it's not a big deal one way or the other. I'm just curious.

Comment: Use `map` function.

Comment: ``blah = random.randint(*map(int, minmax))``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, that's doable:

```
blah = random.randint(*map(int, minmax))
```

Use [`map(int, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to perform the type conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a *list comprehension* expression to type-cast the elements to `int` and then unpack the list as:

```
random.randint(*[int(i) for i in minmax])
#              ^    ^ type-cast minmax elements to `int`
#              ^ unpack the `list`
```