# Expanding tuple arguments while casting to different types

Tags: python, casting, unpack

I've seen [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011757/expand-tuple-into-arguments-while-casting-them) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371269/call-int-function-on-every-list-element) about casting while unpacking strucutures **of the same type**. I.e.

```
def foo():
    return ('1', '2')

x, y = foo()  # as str
x, y = map(int, foo())  # as int
x, y = [int(n) for n in foo()]  # equivalently as int
```

But say you had

```
def foo():
    return ('s', '1')
```

and you wanted to unpack and cast only the second element of the tuple. Of course there is

```
x, y = foo()
y = int(y)
```

which, in the name of simplicity, could definitely be the most pythonic approach. Out of curiosity though, is there an even more succinct way to accomplish the same thing on a single line?

Comment: `[f(v) for f,v in zip([str, int], foo())]` would do it in a single line.  It's also an example of *why* doing things in a single line isn't necessarily a good idea...

Comment: Absolutely - good example. Some of these convoluted approaches crossed my mind. Asking the question only because I couldn't help wonder if there was some slick, pythonic syntax I just haven't encountered yet to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Python 3.8+, you can use assignment expression `:=`

```
def foo():
    return ('s', '1')

x, y = (v:=foo())[0], int(v[1])
print(x, y)
```

Prints:

```
s 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the value is able to be cast to int:

```
x, y = [int(n) if n.isdigit() for n in foo()]
```

Although this won't work for negitive numbers so you could use a try/except clause

```
def convert(s, t=int):
    try:
        return t(s)
    except ValueError:
        return s

x, y = map(convert, foo())
```

Otherwise if you know every first value will be a `str` and the second will be `int` then you can use

```
x, y = foo(); y = int(y)
```

If you insist on a 1 liner